# scala reflection miss inherit class java annotation

Tags: java, scala, reflection, annotations

model code(partly):

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface CoreField {

  String mongoTag() default "";

  boolean needIndex() default false;
}


trait PackItemTrait {

  @BeanProperty
  @CoreField(mongoTag = "num")
  var number: Int = _
}


class UserResourceFragmentT_1 {

  @BeanProperty
  @CoreField(mongoTag = "num")
  var number: Int = _
}


class UserResourceFragmentT_2 extends PackItemTrait {

}
```

reflection code(partly):

```
val className = "xxx.xxxx.UserResourceFragmentT_1" // or UserResourceFragmentT_2 fullNme
val clzSymbol = mirror.staticClass(className)
val clzType = clzSymbol.toType
clzType.members.foreach { each =>
  if (each.isTerm) {
    val eachTerm = each.asTerm
    println("eachTerm:" + eachTerm.name.decoded)
    println("isAccessor:" + eachTerm.isAccessor)
    println("isGetter:" + eachTerm.isGetter)
    println("isSetter:" + eachTerm.isSetter)
    println("isVar:" + eachTerm.isVar)
    println("isVal:" + eachTerm.isVal)
    println("annotation size:" + eachTerm.annotations.size)
    println("")
    if (eachTerm.isVar || eachTerm.isVal) {
```

I test class **UserResourceFragmentT_1** and **UserResourceFragmentT_2**.
When reflect **UserResourceFragmentT_1**, the outprint annotation size is 2, that's right, on the other hand, when reflect **UserResourceFragmentT_2** which is inherit trait class PackItemTrait, the field **number** could be parse, but print is not like to previous model.

println:

**UserResourceFragmentT_1**

```
[info] eachTerm:number
[info] isAccessor:false
[info] isGetter:false
[info] isSetter:false
[info] isVar:true
[info] isVal:false
[info] annotation size:2

[info] eachTerm:number_=
[info] isAccessor:true
[info] isGetter:false
[info] isSetter:true
[info] isVar:false
[info] isVal:false
[info] annotation size:0
```

**UserResourceFragmentT_2**

```
[info] eachTerm:number_=
[info] isAccessor:true
[info] isGetter:false
[info] isSetter:true
[info] isVar:false
[info] isVal:false
[info] annotation size:0

[info] eachTerm:number
[info] isAccessor:true
[info] isGetter:true
[info] isSetter:false
[info] isVar:false
[info] isVal:false
[info] annotation size:0
```

I don't really konw about scala inherit mechanism...
I also test PackItemTrait as **abstract class**, **normal  class**, **case class**, the result are same: **scala reflection api can not parse java annotation with field which inherit from super class**, Any one can help me???

Comment: Could you upload the entire project to github? I'll be glad to take a look.

Comment: There is too much code for entire project, i am not sure you can compile them in sbt easily, it cannot done easily. my problem is easy to reporduce.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako it is simple to reproduce, `runtimeMirror(clazz.getClassLoader).classSymbol(clazz).selfType.members` returns all members including the inherited ones. The problem is that calling `m.annotations` on those inherited members return empty List even though they are annotated...

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I find a way to go:

```
val mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader)
  val clzSymbol = mirror.staticClass("xxx.XXX.UserEquipmentT")
  clzSymbol.baseClasses.filter(
    each => (each.name.decoded != "Any" && each.name.decoded != "Object")
  ).foreach { each =>
    each.asType.toType.members.foreach { each =>
      if (each.isTerm) {
        val eachTerm = each.asTerm
        if (eachTerm.isVal || eachTerm.isVar) {
          println("name:" + eachTerm.name.decoded)
          println("annotation size:" + eachTerm.annotations.size)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't return annotations for inherited members, only direct ones. I don't know if it is bug or it is by design:

```
runtimeMirror(clazz.getClassLoader).classSymbol(clazz).selfType.members.flatMap(m => m.annotations)
```

This however returns annotations even for inherited members:

```
runtimeMirror(clazz.getClassLoader).classSymbol(clazz).baseClasses.map(_.typeSignature).flatMap(c => c.members).flatMap(m => m.annotations)
```